# Trying to display fields from hash but getting undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am receiving the error "**undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass**" when trying to display a field from a json parsed hash.  How do I get the coll_title data to display?

The data from **alinks**:

```
[{
"role"=>"source", 
"relator"=>"dnr", 
"terms"=>[], 
"_resolved"=>{
    "lock_version"=>0, 
    "publish"=>true, 
    "display_name"=>{
        "coll_num"=>"024", 
        "coll_title"=>"Collection Title"
        }
    }
}]
```

The code:

```
def display_agents(hash, opts = {})
  html = "<div><small>"
  html << "<ul style='list-style-type:none'>"
  alinks = JSON.parse( hash["json"] )["linked_agents"]
  alinks.each do |_resolved|
    html << "<li>#{_resolved["display_name"]["coll_title"]}</li>"
  end
  html << "</ul>"
  html << "</small></div><div class='clearfix'></div>"
  html.html_safe
end
```

The call:

```
<td>
  <% if result['primary_type'] === "resource" or result['primary_type'] === "digital_object" or result['primary_type'] === "accession" %>
      <%= display_agents(result) %>
  <% end %>
</td>
```

The error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #85):

82:         <% end %>
83:         <td>
84:           <% if result['primary_type'] === "resource" or result['primary_type'] === "digital_object" or result['primary_type'] === "accession" %>
85:               <%= display_agents(result) %>
86:           <% end %>
87:         </td>
88:         <%#<td>%>
```

Edit: added method call and error display.

Comment: Can you give the line numbers in your code and at which line you are getting the error? Also, how are you calling method `display_agents`?

Comment: added the method call and error display

Comment: and `result` is a hash? The data from alinks: that you have in the question is an array of hashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the data from alinks you show is the linked_agents array (it's not 100% clear from your question) - then you need

```
alinks.each do |agent_link|
  html << "<li>#{agent_link["_resolved"]["display_name"]["coll_title"]}</li>"
end
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `_resolved` in your `each` block is the entire hash, ie. with your example data, it's equal to:

```
{
"role"=>"source", 
"relator"=>"dnr", 
"terms"=>[], 
"_resolved"=>{
    "lock_version"=>0, 
    "publish"=>true, 
    "display_name"=>{
        "coll_num"=>"024", 
        "coll_title"=>"Collection Title"
        }
    }
}
```

Can you see why retrieving the `"display_name"` key of **that** hash is returning `nil`?